# android gradle build error Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my Android Studio Package 6.0 but after updating when i try to build my working project i always get this error warning Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy
I already researched it but not resolving my issue. And the same project is running fine in other machine. Please help me guys

Comment: Apache HttpClient is deprecated on Android, and has been for a long time. Consider using something else.

Answer (score 2):

It is deprecated long time before but after updating package to 6.0 this issue arises. but now it is resolved. I have to add Json array with file named as optional.json in my sdk path. 
Json Array :
[{"name": "org.apache.http.legacy","jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar","manifest": false}]